# Highcharts - x-axis date interval data values count must be 12

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have designed a spline highcharts JSFiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/s9qwj1h3/) where I need help in below 2 points:

1. x-axis date values count should be 12 irrespective of data. If I get 1 year data or 3 or 5 year data, count on x-axis should be 12. I tried tickpositions and tickpositioner but not able to resolve my issue.
2. data plotting should start after the color plot bands. data plotting should not be on the color plotbands. it should plot after the color plotbands.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            height: 250
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        legend: {
            align: "center",
            layout: "horizontal",
            verticalAlign: "bottom",
            alignColumns: false,
            itemDistance: 10,
            symbolHeight: 12,
            symbolWidth: 12,
            itemStyle: {
                fontSize: "11px !important"
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                millisecond: '%b-%d-%Y',
                second: '%b-%d-%Y',
                minute: '%b-%d-%Y',
                hour: '%b-%d-%Y',
                day: '%b-%d-%Y',
                week: '%b-%d-%Y',
                month: '%b-%d-%Y',
                year: '%Y'
            },
            min: null,
            max: null,
            labels: {
                style: {
                    fontSize: "10px !important",
                    color: "#000"
                }
            },
            gridLineColor: "transparent",
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            lineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            lineColor: "transparent",
            tickLength: 0,
            style: {
                fontSize: "10px !important",
                color: "#000"
            }
        },
        yAxis: [
            {
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                width: 20,
                tickInterval: 20,
                plotBands: [
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(204,0,0)',
                        from: 0,
                        to: 30.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(226,113,113)',
                        from: 31,
                        to: 44.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(247,209,34)',
                        from: 45,
                        to: 54.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(136,207,136)',
                        from: 55,
                        to: 68.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(68,180,68)',
                        from: 69,
                        to: 87.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(0,153,0)',
                        from: 88,
                        to: 100,
                        zIndex: 3
                    }
                ],
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                title: {
                    text: ""
                },
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: 'black'
                    },
                    x: -7,
                    y: 3,
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value;
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                linkedTo: 0,
                gridLineColor: 'white',
                lineColor: "transparent",
                title: {
                    text: ""
                },
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        ],
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter() {
                        return "";
                    }
                }
            },
            series: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    inactive: {
                        opacity: 1
                    }
                },
                enableMouseTracking: true,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
                threshold: 0, // let zero values have some height
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                minPointLength: 10,
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function () {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: false,
            shared: false,
            followPointer: false,
            formatter: function () {
                return this.point.tooltip;
            }
        },
        series: [
        {
                    "color": "rgb(0,187,221)",
                    "data": [
                    {"x":1601490600000,"y":25},
                    {"x":1601577000000,"y":34},
                    { "x":1601663400000,"y":10},
                    { "x":1601749800000,"y":12},
                    { "x":1601836200000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1601922600000,"y":28},
                    { "x":1602009000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1602095400000,"y":22},
                    { "x":1602181800000,"y":24},
                    { "x":1602268200000,"y":44},
                    { "x":1602354600000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1602441000000,"y":34},
                    { "x":1602527400000,"y":10},
                    { "x":1602613800000,"y":12},
                    { "x":1602700200000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1602786600000,"y":28},
                    { "x":1602873000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1602959400000,"y":22},
                    { "x":1603045800000,"y":24},
                    { "x":1603132200000,"y":44},
                    { "x":1603218600000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1603305000000,"y":34},
                    { "x":1603391400000,"y":10},
                    { "x":1603477800000,"y":12},
                    { "x":1603564200000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1603650600000,"y":28},
                    { "x":1603737000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1603823400000,"y":22},
                    { "x":1603909800000,"y":24},
                    { "x":1603996200000,"y":44},
                    { "x":1604169000000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1604255400000,"y":34},
                    { "x":1604341800000,"y":10},
                    { "x":1604428200000,"y":12},
                    { "x":1604514600000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1604601000000,"y":28},
                    { "x":1604687400000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1604773800000,"y":22},
                    { "x":1604860200000,"y":24},
                    { "x":1604946600000,"y":44},
                    { "x":1605033000000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1605119400000,"y":34},
                    { "x":1605205800000,"y":10},
                    { "x":1605292200000,"y":12},
                    { "x":1605378600000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1605465000000,"y":28},
                    { "x":1605551400000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1605637800000,"y":22},
                    { "x":1605724200000,"y":24},
                    { "x":1605810600000,"y":44}
                 ],
                    "name": 'ABC',
                    "type": 'spline'
                },
                {
                    "color": "rgb(154,2,42)",
                    "data": [
                    {"x":1601490600000,"y":50},
                    {"x":1601577000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1601663400000,"y":40},
                    { "x":1601749800000,"y":42},
                    { "x":1601836200000,"y":86},
                    { "x":1601922600000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1602009000000,"y":60},
                    { "x":1602095400000,"y":75},
                    { "x":1602181800000,"y":80},
                    { "x":1602268200000,"y":85},
                    { "x":1602354600000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1602441000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1602527400000,"y":40},
                    { "x":1602613800000,"y":42},
                    { "x":1602700200000,"y":86},
                    { "x":1602786600000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1602873000000,"y":60},
                    { "x":1602959400000,"y":75},
                    { "x":1603045800000,"y":80},
                    { "x":1603132200000,"y":85},
                    { "x":1603218600000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1603305000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1603391400000,"y":40},
                    { "x":1603477800000,"y":42},
                    { "x":1603564200000,"y":86},
                    { "x":1603650600000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1603737000000,"y":60},
                    { "x":1603823400000,"y":75},
                    { "x":1603909800000,"y":80},
                    { "x":1603996200000,"y":85},
                    { "x":1604169000000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1604255400000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1604341800000,"y":40},
                    { "x":1604428200000,"y":42},
                    { "x":1604514600000,"y":86},
                    { "x":1604601000000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1604687400000,"y":60},
                    { "x":1604773800000,"y":75},
                    { "x":1604860200000,"y":80},
                    { "x":1604946600000,"y":85},
                    { "x":1605033000000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1605119400000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1605205800000,"y":40},
                    { "x":1605292200000,"y":42},
                    { "x":1605378600000,"y":86},
                    { "x":1605465000000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1605551400000,"y":60},
                    { "x":1605637800000,"y":75},
                    { "x":1605724200000,"y":80},
                    { "x":1605810600000,"y":85}
                    ],
                    "name": 'XYZ',
                    "type": 'spline'
                }
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can show the first 12 ticks using `max`, if you want to show 12 ticks for the whole data series I believe you would need to preprocess the data. Maybe the data grouping function in Highcharts Stock could manage it.
2. You have to account for the width of the Y axis and the plotbands, and offset the xAxis using the `left` option.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            height: 250,
            spacingRight: 100,
            events: {
                load: function () {
            let data = this.series[0].data
            this.update({xAxis: {max: data[12].x}}, true)
              }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        legend: {
            align: "center",
            layout: "horizontal",
            verticalAlign: "bottom",
            alignColumns: false,
            itemDistance: 10,
            symbolHeight: 12,
            symbolWidth: 12,
            itemStyle: {
                fontSize: "11px !important"
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            // Must offset for xAxis + plotBand width
            left: 60,
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                millisecond: '%b-%d-%Y',
                second: '%b-%d-%Y',
                minute: '%b-%d-%Y',
                hour: '%b-%d-%Y',
                day: '%b-%d-%Y',
                week: '%b-%d-%Y',
                month: '%b-%d-%Y',
                year: '%Y'
            },
            min: null,
            max: 12,
            labels: {
                style: {
                    fontSize: "10px !important",
                    color: "#000"
                },
            },
            gridLineColor: "transparent",
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            lineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            lineColor: "black",
            tickLength: 0,
            style: {
                fontSize: "10px !important",
                color: "#000"
            }
        },
        yAxis: [
            {
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                width: 20,
                tickInterval: 20,
                plotBands: [
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(204,0,0)',
                        from: 0,
                        to: 30.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(226,113,113)',
                        from: 31,
                        to: 44.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(247,209,34)',
                        from: 45,
                        to: 54.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(136,207,136)',
                        from: 55,
                        to: 68.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(68,180,68)',
                        from: 69,
                        to: 87.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(0,153,0)',
                        from: 88,
                        to: 100,
                        zIndex: 3
                    }
                ],
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                title: {
                    text: ""
                },
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: 'black'
                    },
                    x: -7,
                    y: 3,
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value;
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                linkedTo: 0,
                gridLineColor: 'white',
                lineColor: "transparent",
                title: {
                    text: ""
                },
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        ],
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter() {
                        return "";
                    }
                }
            },
            series: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    inactive: {
                        opacity: 1
                    }
                },
                enableMouseTracking: true,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
                threshold: 0, // let zero values have some height
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                minPointLength: 10,
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function () {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: false,
            shared: false,
            followPointer: false,
            formatter: function () {
                return this.point.tooltip;
            }
        },
        series: [
        {
                    "color": "rgb(0,187,221)",
                    "data": [
                    {"x":1601490600000,"y":25},
                    {"x":1601577000000,"y":34},
                    { "x":1601663400000,"y":10},
                    { "x":1601749800000,"y":12},
                    { "x":1601836200000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1601922600000,"y":28},
                    { "x":1602009000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1602095400000,"y":22},
                    { "x":1602181800000,"y":24},
                    { "x":1602268200000,"y":44},
                    { "x":1602354600000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1602441000000,"y":34},
                    { "x":1602527400000,"y":10},
                    { "x":1602613800000,"y":12},
                    { "x":1602700200000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1602786600000,"y":28},
                    { "x":1602873000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1602959400000,"y":22},
                    { "x":1603045800000,"y":24},
                    { "x":1603132200000,"y":44},
                    { "x":1603218600000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1603305000000,"y":34},
                    { "x":1603391400000,"y":10},
                    { "x":1603477800000,"y":12},
                    { "x":1603564200000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1603650600000,"y":28},
                    { "x":1603737000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1603823400000,"y":22},
                    { "x":1603909800000,"y":24},
                    { "x":1603996200000,"y":44},
                    { "x":1604169000000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1604255400000,"y":34},
                    { "x":1604341800000,"y":10},
                    { "x":1604428200000,"y":12},
                    { "x":1604514600000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1604601000000,"y":28},
                    { "x":1604687400000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1604773800000,"y":22},
                    { "x":1604860200000,"y":24},
                    { "x":1604946600000,"y":44},
                    { "x":1605033000000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1605119400000,"y":34},
                    { "x":1605205800000,"y":10},
                    { "x":1605292200000,"y":12},
                    { "x":1605378600000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1605465000000,"y":28},
                    { "x":1605551400000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1605637800000,"y":22},
                    { "x":1605724200000,"y":24},
                    { "x":1605810600000,"y":44}
                 ],
                    "name": 'ABC',
                    "type": 'spline'
                },
                {
                    "color": "rgb(154,2,42)",
                    "data": [
                    {"x":1601490600000,"y":50},
                    {"x":1601577000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1601663400000,"y":40},
                    { "x":1601749800000,"y":42},
                    { "x":1601836200000,"y":86},
                    { "x":1601922600000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1602009000000,"y":60},
                    { "x":1602095400000,"y":75},
                    { "x":1602181800000,"y":80},
                    { "x":1602268200000,"y":85},
                    { "x":1602354600000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1602441000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1602527400000,"y":40},
                    { "x":1602613800000,"y":42},
                    { "x":1602700200000,"y":86},
                    { "x":1602786600000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1602873000000,"y":60},
                    { "x":1602959400000,"y":75},
                    { "x":1603045800000,"y":80},
                    { "x":1603132200000,"y":85},
                    { "x":1603218600000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1603305000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1603391400000,"y":40},
                    { "x":1603477800000,"y":42},
                    { "x":1603564200000,"y":86},
                    { "x":1603650600000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1603737000000,"y":60},
                    { "x":1603823400000,"y":75},
                    { "x":1603909800000,"y":80},
                    { "x":1603996200000,"y":85},
                    { "x":1604169000000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1604255400000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1604341800000,"y":40},
                    { "x":1604428200000,"y":42},
                    { "x":1604514600000,"y":86},
                    { "x":1604601000000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1604687400000,"y":60},
                    { "x":1604773800000,"y":75},
                    { "x":1604860200000,"y":80},
                    { "x":1604946600000,"y":85},
                    { "x":1605033000000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1605119400000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1605205800000,"y":40},
                    { "x":1605292200000,"y":42},
                    { "x":1605378600000,"y":86},
                    { "x":1605465000000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1605551400000,"y":60},
                    { "x":1605637800000,"y":75},
                    { "x":1605724200000,"y":80},
                    { "x":1605810600000,"y":85}
                    ],
                    "name": 'XYZ',
                    "type": 'spline'
                }
        ]
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: After adding the left property to 60, the chart completely goes outside of the chart box. Can we have a solution for that also?  chart: {
            height: 220,
            plotBorderWidth: 1
        },

Comment: @Ronak can use chart.spacingRight to accommodate for the offset.

Comment: @Marensiuns Pettersen - Can you help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68374543/highcharts-with-yaxis-max-property-doesnt-hide-plotbands-and-lables ?